# Duvida conceitual. Entity Framework, BLL e OOP

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, entity-framework

Pessoas,

Solicito ajuda urgente...

Eu tenho um sistema que está rodando "certinho". Feito em C# (WinForm) e SQL Server (sem EntityFramework).
Porém, devido a estudos e a necessidade de ampliação do sistema (adição de novas funcionalidades e melhoria em outras partes) estou refazendo o sistema inteiro.

Eu acha que sabia OOP e que o sistema estava orientado a objetos. Grande inocência da minha parte.

Estou estudando fortemente OOP e percebi as atrocidades que cometi no meu sistema, por isso o reinicio. Porém, como estou dando um passo de cada vez e tentando fazer tudo certo desde o início para não ter que refazer novamente.

Eis que surgiu minha dúvida. Vou tentar exemplificar.

Minha camada BLL tem:

```
public class PessoaFisica
{
    public string Nome { get; private set; }
    public Enum.Sexo Sexo { get; private set; }
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; private set; }
    public int? Idade { get; private set; }
    public Enum.EstadoCivil EstadoCivil { get; private set; }
    public string CPF { get; private set; }
    public string DocumentoIdentificacao { get; private set; }
    public string Nacionalidade { get; private set; }
    public string NacionalidadeComplemento { get; private set; }
    public Enum.Estados NaturalidadeEstado { get; private set; }
    public string NaturalidadeCidade { get; private set; }
    public string Profissao { get; private set; }
    public Endereco Endereco { get; private set; }
}
```

E algumas classes que herdam de PessoaFisica, como exemplo, segue uma:

```
public class Genitor : PessoaFisica
{
    public Enum.SituacaoGenitor SituacaoGenior { get; private set; }
    public Enum.Estados FalecimentoEstado { get; private set; }
    public string FalecimentoCidade { get; private set; }
    public string FalecimentoData { get; private set; }
    public string TempoDesaparecimento { get; private set; }
    public bool ApresentaDocIdentificacao { get; private set; } = true;
    public bool NecessidadeTestemunha { get; private set; } = false;
    public bool Assina { get; private set; } = true;
    public bool NecessidadeInterprete { get; private set; } = false;
}
```

Ok. Até aqui... acredito que não tenha grandes problemas.
Essas classes são reflexos das minhas telas.

Estou utilizando Entity Framework (Code First) para comunicação com a base de dados (SQL Server).

Tenho por exemplo, a seguinte entidade no EF:

```
public partial class Genitor
{
    public int IdGenitor { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Nascimento { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Idade { get; set; }
    public string Profissao { get; set; }
    public string Nacionalidade { get; set; }
    public string NaturalidadeEstado { get; set; }
    public string NaturalidadeCidade { get; set; }
    public string Falecido { get; set; }
    public string DataFalecimento { get; set; }
    public string FalecimentoEstado { get; set; }
    public string FalecimentoCidade { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdUsuario { get; set; }
    public string Situacao { get; set; }
    public string DocIdentificacao { get; set; }
    public string Endereco { get; set; }
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    public string TempoDesaparecimento { get; set; }
    public string ApresentaDocIdentificacao { get; set; }
    public string NecessidadeTestemunha { get; set; }
    public string Assina { get; set; }
    public string NecessidadeInterprete { get; set; }
    public virtual Usuario Usuario { get; set; }
}
```

Eis a minha dúvida:

Está certo ter duas classes para a "mesma" coisa?
Como assim mesma coisa? Explico: Duas classes (uma na BLL e outra no EF) para o Genitor.

Na classe que está no BLL, eu tenho tipos específicos de dados (Enum, etc) que são "impossíveis" no EF.

Então como fazer? Criar uma camada entre a BLL e DAL para "mapear" isso? Explicando para a entidade do EF como a classe do BLL funciona?
Acho que não... pois isso causaria um grande acoplamento.

Ou o certo é apenas utilizar as entidades do EF (DAL) para os dados... ou seja, criar o objeto Genitor (entidade do EF) quando clicar no botão para gravar os dados e mandar o EF persistir esses dados?

Não sei se me fiz entender corretamente... mas estou com essa dúvida.

Não encontrei exemplos de sistemas para ver como é resolvido isso.

Desde já, grato pela ajuda de todos.

Comment: Jovem, enum é considerado como int no entity framework. Não vejo nenhum tipo de dado "impossível" no EF.

Comment: @jbueno, obrigado pela resposta. Eu sei que um Enum converte para int, mas isso não fica estranho? Sendo sexo Masculino e Feminimo... não 0 e 1... a leitura dos dados do banco não fica prejudicada?

Answer (score 0):

Eu particularmente não sou fã de EF, mas respondendo sua pergunta, se as classes são exatamente as mesmas, há um problema, pois demonstra uma fragilidade na sua arquitetura. Isto é, se amanhã ou depois um novo campo aparecer, você terá que alterar nas duas classes, correto?

Como dito nos comentários, eu faria o mapeamento para a classe que possui o Enum e removeria a outra.

Obs: faça o mapeamento via Fluent API para não sujar sua classe de domínio com código de infraestrutura (persistência).